# Confusion over dmultinom function arguments and meaning with respect to Math

Tags: r, probability, density-function, multinomial-distribution, notation

What do the arguments in the dmultinom function mean?

```
dmultinom(x, size = NULL, prob, log = FALSE)
Arguments

x   
vector of length K of integers in 0:size.

n   
number of random vectors to draw.

size    
integer, say N, specifying the total number of objects that are put into K boxes in the typical multinomial experiment. For dmultinom, it defaults to sum(x).

prob    
numeric non-negative vector of length K, specifying the probability for the K classes; is internally normalized to sum 1. Infinite and missing values are not allowed.

log 
logical; if TRUE, log probabilities are computed.
```

What is $x$?

what is prob?

What does dmultinom calculate? The probability? The probability of what?

What's the mathematical notation explanation for dmultinom?

Would someone please translate this programming language into integrals and pdfs and mathematical language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multinomial distribution is a generalization of the binomial distribution. As with all distribution functions in R, the first letter of the name indicates what is returned, i.e., `d<distribution>` functions usually return a probability density. Since the multinomial distribution is discrete, `dmultinom` is actually the [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) of the multinomial distribution.

> What is x?

x is a vector containing the number of balls for each "bucket".

> what is prob?

This is explained well in the documentation. It's the probability for one item to be in each of the "buckets".

> What does dmultinom calculate?

The probability of observing the specified numbers of items in the buckets.

> What's the mathematical notation explanation for dmultinom?

The mathematical notation is provided in the documentation, i.e., `help("dmultinom")`:

> $P(X[1]=x[1], … , X[K]=x[k]) = C * prod(j=1 , …, K) p[j]^{x[j]}$
>
> where $C$ is the ‘multinomial coefficient’ $C = N! / (x[1]! * … *
> > x[K]!)$ and $N = sum(j=1, …, K) x[j]$.

You can also find it in the Wikipedia article about the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

It might be helpful to compare with equivalent code for the binomial distribution:

Lets assume we have 10 balls and two buckets. The probability to put a ball into bucket A is 25 % and into bucket B is 75 %. We are interested in the probability of having the same number of balls in both buckets.

With `dmultinom`:

```
dmultinom(c(5, 5), size = 10, prob = c(0.25, 0.75))
#[1] 0.0583992
```

With `dbinom`:

```
dbinom(5, size = 10, prob = 0.25)
#[1] 0.0583992
```